# Scatter Plot Manipulation: restricting data within a time frame and checking how many events happened

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on a project and have a scatterplot with Y axis as numerical ekg reading and X axis as the dates those reading were taken.

My next step is to look at the data to within 1 year of pacemaker insertion and check if we have enough reading within that 1 year to compare with each other. Ex. if a patient had pacemaker placed on 6/2017. I'm checking to see if I have enough ekg data values from 6/2016 - 6/2018 and for each month within that timeframe. Some patients have that, other don't. This will allow me to look at trends correlated with months i.e changes at the 1 month mark after treatment with the ekg reading done 1 month prior to that treatment, changes at the 9 month after treatment with the ekg reading done 1 month prior to that treatment.

I already have a scatterplot with a wide range of dates going back to 5-10 years. Is there a tutorial on how to do this. If I'm able to restrict the data, have some vertical lines drawn on scatterplot for each month for up to a year both pre and post pacemaker insertion, it'll allow me to quickly visualize and get these values instead of having to go through a huge excel sheet.

This the code I'm running right now that gave me the scatterplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

library(tidyverse)

library(lubridate)

d <- read.csv("PacemakerData/test.csv",)

d

d$neworder_dt <- mdy(d$order_dt)

ggplot(d, aes(x = neworder_dt, y = egkreading)) + geom_point() + geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.Date("1999-2-2")), linetype=4)
```

the geomv_line code I added represents when the pt underwent pacemaker procedure

Don't know how to proceed

Comment: Welcome to SO auto. It will be easier to answer your question if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example). Given your data are likely to be confidential, you can just make a 'dummy' version that replicates the structure of your real data. If you can't work out how to generate 'dummy' data, provide a detailed explanation of your fields, what constitutes " enough ekg data values" etc. Thanks